# Looking for the end of aac stream

Tags: mp4, aac

I am looking for the end of aac in mp4 file. In the internet, I found the suggestion that one needs to find binary 111, 7 in decimal from the end.
However, after analysing the aac,  some aac sample do not seem to end with END element (7).
Any idea why is it so? How can I find the end of aac stream in those cases?

Comment: Just as a general hint did you try to read the specs? There it should be pointed out.

Comment: What specs dod you mean?

Comment: Of the aac format/encoding.

Comment: It looks complicated for other cases than END element and I have not found a decent exact good specification.